# How to extract img src from web page via lxml in beautifulsoup using python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am new in python and I am working on web scraping project from amazon and I have a problem on how to extract the product img src from product page via lxml using BeautifulSoup

I tried the following code to extract it but it doesn't show the url of the img.

here is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/crocs-Unisex-Classic-Black-Women/dp/B0014C0LSY/ref=sr_1_2?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560091629&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-2&th=1&psc=1'

r = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

img = s.find(class_="imgTagWrapper").img['src']
# I tried this code.

print(img)
```

I tried this code...but it shows like this:

data:image/jpeg;base64,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....//

any help ?

Comment: It appears that what you are getting back is the actually binary JPEG data, not a link to an image. Further, the binary data has been encoded as base64. You might check the source web page to see if it contains a link or the image itself. If the latter, then there is no link to be had. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is the base64 encoding of the image. What you do with it depends on what you're doing with image URLs.

Comment: Yes this is base64 encoding image but I tried with 'html.parser' it extracts the img src link normally.

Answer (score 0):

The image you like to grab from that page is available in the value of this key `data-a-dynamic-image`. There are multiple images with different sizes in there. All you need to do now is create a conditional statement to isolate that image containing `395`.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/crocs-Unisex-Classic-Black-Women/dp/B0014C0LSY/ref=sr_1_2?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560091629&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-2&th=1&psc=1'

r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
img = s.find(id="landingImage")['data-a-dynamic-image']
img = json.loads(img)
for k,v in img.items():
    if '395' in k:
        print(k)
```

Output:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71oNMAAC7sL._UX395_.jpg
```

In that case try like this and pick the one suits your need:

```
for k,v in img.items():
    print(k)
```

Comment: It works Thanks SIM , but what about another products ? , I tried to extract data from another item but it hasn't img link with size '395'!.....here is the link https://www.amazon.com/Viishow-Printed-Dresses-Pockets-Wine/dp/B07PMHY51F/ref=sr_1_3?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560098637&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-3&th=1&psc=1

Comment: I don't see how this works. I've tried the json.loads() line and I get BS4 object is not a string error. When I convert the result to str() it actually crashed PyCharm (windows 10)