# Extract a img URL with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am looking to scrape the image URL from Amazon but I dont get it. Thats my code right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

URL = "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01NCX7I5P/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=A30K5QJOZDKVAA&psc=1"

response = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

img = soup.find(class_="imgTagWrapper")

print(img)
```

and that is my output:

```
<div class="imgTagWrapper" id="imgTagWrapperId">
<img alt="TURATA Digitaler Messschieber IPX54 Wasserdichte Schieblehre Edelstahl 150 mm / 6 Zoll f&amp;uuml;r Abst&amp;auml;nden, Durchmesser, Tiefenma&amp;szlig;, mit LCD Display Profimessger&amp;auml;t" class="a-dynamic-image a-stretch-horizontal" data-a-dynamic-image='{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385]}' data-a-image-name="landingImage" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SL1500_.jpg" id="landingImage" onload="if(this.width/this.height &gt; 1.0){this.className += ' a-stretch-horizontal'}else{this.className += ' a-stretch-vertical'};this.onload='';" src="
data:image/jpeg;base64,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 Thread 'MainThread' (0x1) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
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

" style="max-width:522px;max-height:522px;"/>
</div>
```

I need  the URL "[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL.*SX342*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61JepX9ctWL._SX342_.jpg)" and it should be individual so that I can change the product URL and still get the same first picture that Amazon shows. I also watched this thread: [How to extract img src from web page via lxml in beautifulsoup using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519505/how-to-extract-img-src-from-web-page-via-lxml-in-beautifulsoup-using-python) but it isn't individual.

I hope anyone can help me and the scraped part looks a little bit different to the html code that I watched with Google Chrome

Comment: That URL is dynamically generated. You cannot extract it with `requests`. You must use `selenium`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping program cannot find element which I can see in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904786/web-scraping-program-cannot-find-element-which-i-can-see-in-the-browser)

Comment: Oh yes. But luckly Ahmed Soliman found another atribute :)